# Listing every single possibility of combinations without repetition of 20 elements

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

I want to find out "an easy way in math" to list every single possibility of 20 elements(let's say the elements are from letter A to T) grouped in two without repetition (20 choice 2). I know how to calculate the number of all possibilities which is 190, but what about a way in Math finding out a list showing every single possibility of these combinations. I know how to find out a list of small choices (e.g, 3 choices A,B, C that the list of every single possibility without repetitions will be **AB, AC, BC**). But what about a large list of 190 possibilities generated from 20 elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can list each pair of elements that contains $A$, then each pair of elements that contains $B$ other than $AB$, then each pair of elements that contains $C$ other than $AC$ and $BC$, and so forth
\begin{array}{l l l l l l}
\{A, B\}, & \{A, C\}, & \{A, D\}, & \{A, E\}, & \{A, F\}, & \ldots\\
& \{B, C\}, & \{B, D\}, & \{B, E\}, & \{B, F\}, & \ldots\\
& & \{C, D\}, & \{C, E\}, & \{C, F\}, & \ldots
\end{array}
Observe that there are $19$ elements in the first row, $18$ in the second row, $17$ in the third row, and so forth.  In general, the $k$th row has $20 - k$ elements.  Notice that 
$$19 + 18 + 17 + \ldots + 3 + 2 + 1 + 0 = \frac{20(0 + 19)}{2} = \frac{20 \cdot 19}{2} = 10 \cdot 19 = 190$$
where we have used the formula 
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} k = 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + \ldots + n - 1 = \frac{n(n - 1)}{2} = \binom{n}{2}$$ 
The formula 
$$\binom{n}{2} = \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} k$$
follows from the observation that of the $\binom{n}{2}$ subsets of the set $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, n\}$, there are $k - 1$ two-element subsets whose greatest element is $k$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an unordered pair.
Let $S$ be the set of all possibilities. Then
$$S=\{\{a,b\} \mid a\neq b\} $$
where $a,b\in \{A,B,C,...,T\}$